# Laravel/MySQL - Does `WhereIn` have any limitation for the array passed in?

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb

My code:

```
$first = FirstModel::where('status', 1)->get();
SecondModel::whereIn('id', $first->pluck('id')->toArray())->delete();
```

What if `$first->pluck('id')->toArray()` has more than 1000 ids? Does it have any limitation?

Comment: it will take O(n) time where n is the number of elements in array you are inserting to search

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in

Comment: The number of values in the IN() list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value.